# Package.json scripts environment variables

Tags: webpack, arguments, package.json

This works from the terminal:

```
STORYBOOK_THEME=red npm run storybook
```

How do I write this in the scripts section in package.json?

Comment: the same thing.

Comment: No, it does not.

Comment: Gives me the following error: 'STORYBOOK_THEME' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: Which OS is yours?

Comment: Windows 10. Some ideas?

Comment: Found the answer. You have to put env before the variabel